# Android studio not fetching libs for my android twitter app

Tags: twitter, android-studio, android-twitter

```
dependencies {
   compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:1.2.0@aar') {
       transitive = true;
    }
}
```

As described in 
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twittercore

But It is not Importing library

Android studio error

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the Fabric/Twitter Maven repository at the top of your `build.gradle`?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: No I don't have Idea about this. Now I have tried but still same problem

Comment: Are you working offline? Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Offline work. Make sure that box is unticked.

Comment: Also: are you using the Fabric Android Studio plugin? It sets all of this up for you and makes life _really_ easy.

Comment: No it is online, I am able to checkin my code to git Hub

Comment: Did you check the setting?

Comment: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
   > Could not find io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.1
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.1/fabric-1.3.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.1/fabric-1.3.1.aar
         file:/E:/......./fabric/1.3.1/fabric-1.3.1.pom
         file:/........./io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/1.3.1/fabric-1.3.1.aar

  Required
         TestingApp:app:unspecified > com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:1.2.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80472/discussion-between-lokesh-tiwari-and-adam-s).

Comment: https://twittersdk.artifactoryonline.com/twittersdk/  this is location from where i am downloading and putting on required location

Answer (score 0):

I found answer as per suggestion by "Adam S" below 
Simply install fabric plugin from here 
https://get.fabric.io/native-social
and thats it see the magic
Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217087/adam-s